# Trouble getting started with NodeJS and SocketIO

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to get a basic structure going using [socket.io](http://socket.io/) and [node.js](http://nodejs.org) while implementing the tcp functionality shown on the home-page of node.js using the `('net')` to create a server.

As there's not much code, here's what I have so far

**Server:**

```
// Setup the server
var tcpProtocol = require('net');
var serverListener = tcpProtocol.createServer(tcpHandler);
var socketIO = require('socket.io').listen(serverListener);

function tcpHandler(socket) {
    console.log("TCP Handler received a call.");
    socket.pipe(socket);
}

socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection maid.");
});

socketIO.sockets.on('login', function(username, password) {
    console.log("login called.");
    console.log('username: ' + username);
    console.log('password: ' + password);
});


serverListener.listen(5055, '127.0.0.1');

console.log("Server started on port 5055");
```

**Then ofcourse, the client:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Client</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.socket.io/socket.io-1.2.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:5055');
        $(function() {
          socket.emit('login', 'Chris', 'PassBob');
            console.log("sent");
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The server is printing out the call for the tcpHandler, however the socketIO calls aren't getting any recognition. The `sent` from the client is printed, however I notice that the `tcpHandler` call gets called repetitively a few times, like it's still attempting to send the data after it failed or something? Just an assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should handle your sockets logic inside the `connection` event.

Your code should look like this:

**Server**

```
socketIO.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("Connection maid.");

    socket.on('login', function(username, password) {
        console.log("login called.");
        console.log('username: ' + username);
        console.log('password: ' + password);
    });
});
```

You can refer to this open-source project - it has lot of sockets logic inside (highlighted)

https://github.com/thecatontheflat/agile-estimation/blob/0.0.3/server.js#L94-L196

Even though the code is dirty, I believe you can get lot of useful examples from there

Comment: Ah! I see! All of the posts and explanation videos I have seen stated that `socketIO.sockets.on` applied a handler to all sockets, this seems true, but also false at the same time, any comments?

Comment: @Christian.tucker Could you give a concrete example so I could analyze it and comment? :)

Comment: For example, `socketIO.sockets.on('message', function(data) { } )` applies the listener for the network-message labeled as `message`. This would handle every message coming in that was identified as `message` be handled by the anonymous function. However, if I want justify a custom name, and not the generic `message` then it has to be done inside of the connection, or bound to each socket individually? I watched an hour long seminar on socket.io / nodejs and this wasn't explained. It was just said that sockets.on applied to all, while "socket"(or whatever you name it) is bound to a single conn

Comment: Well, it seems to be pretty clear in the examples from the documentation - http://socket.io/docs/ :)

Comment: Our definitions of clear documentation are completely different, is this really even considered a documentation? Lol. There's a few code samples and a basic (very short) generic discription. "This class does this." -- Considering just starting Javascript yesterday, I can definately say I'm more used to the Java Documentation where information is actually provided. ;P...

`in short, this documentation doesn't help me understand at all.` -- Even in the Server API page, the actual discussion on the binding of listeners to the sockets are very limited/not discussed at all.

Comment: @Christian.tucker Well, you're right :D Sorry. Welcome to the node.js / sockets world. You'll have to do lot of stuff here by random exploration :D

Comment: **JOY TO THE WORLD.... THE LORD HAS COME...** e.o... Fun, fun, fun.. Slowly learning towards just writing a websocket server in Java. Thanks for all the help though! Already have a working multiplayer 2D rpg prototype running.